I'm making a music player, it gives an error in the lines recycler_view.LayoutManager = LayoutManager recycler_view.adapter = songListAdapter
I'm new to android development, I decided to write a music player, but it gives an error in the lines recycler_view.LayoutManager = LayoutManager and in recycler_view.adapter = songListAdapter. I don't understand what the problem might be, could those who know tell me? Here is the code from MainActivity:
package com.example.zevamusic

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.zevamusic.adapters.SongListAdapter
import com.example.zevamusic.model.SongModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var songModelData:ArrayList<SongModel> = ArrayList()
    var songListAdapter:SongListAdapter?=null

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        var songCursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,null,null,null)
        while (songCursor!=null && songCursor.moveToNext()){
            var songName = songCursor.getString(songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
            var songDuration = songCursor.getString(songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
            songModelData.add(SongModel(songName,songDuration))
        }
        songListAdapter = SongListAdapter(songModelData)
        var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        recycler_view.LayoutManager = layoutManager
        recycler_view.adapter = songListAdapter
    }
}

Here is the code from SongListAdapter:
package com.example.zevamusic.adapters

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.zevamusic.R
import com.example.zevamusic.model.SongModel

class SongListAdapter(SongModel:ArrayList<SongModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<SongListAdapter.SongListViewHolder>() {

    var mSongModel = SongModel

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mSongModel.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongListViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.music_row,parent,false)
        return SongListViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var model = mSongModel[position]
        var songName = model.mSongName
        var songDuration = model.mSongDuration
        holder!!.songTV.text = songName
        holder.durationTV.text = songDuration
    }



    class SongListViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var songTV:TextView
        var durationTV:TextView
        var albumnAtr:ImageView
        init {
            songTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name_tv)
            durationTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_duration_tv)
            albumnAtr = itemView.findViewById(R.id.al_image_view)

        }
    }
}

Here is the code from SongModel:
package com.example.zevamusic.model

class SongModel(songName: String,songDuration:String) {
    var mSongName = songName
    var mSongDuration = songDuration

}

I am making this application based on a video clip, I noticed in it the import of which I did not have(import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*), I decided to add it, but for some reason the word android is lit in red in this import and I tried to fix the problem in import, but I still didn't figure out what the problem was.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your syntax to add layout manager is wrong.
You can add layout manager in 2 ways.

Its layoutManager not LayoutManager.

// deafault orientation is VERTICAL. replace the context accordingly.
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager( context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false) 


You can directly add layout manager to XML file.

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

       //like here
       app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
       //you can also set orientation like this
       android:orientation="vertical"

